# run system() call in R for command line tool

Tags: xml, r, csv, cmd

I am trying to write a script in which I need to run a command line tool to parse the xml to csv file. it works as this:

```
XmlToCsv.Console.exe -xml file.xml -dir C:/Desktop.
```

So I replicated this in R as

```
system('XmlToCsv.Console.exe -xml file.xml -dir C:/Desktop')
```

but it is not working. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: You can read XML files in R so there is no need for the conversion.

Comment: have you checked your working directory ?

Comment: Do you get an error message?  What does the message say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible issues:

Is the location really `C:/Desktop`?  If you have spaces in your path, then that path needs to be wrapped in quotes, and probably needs to already exist.  (I don't know if `XmlToCsv.Console.exe` will create it automatically if it doesn't.)

If you are using Windows then `XmlToCsv.Console.exe` should be contained in a folder listed in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: thanks. i added it to the PATH environment variable, and it works now.

Comment: @Lawrence Glad to be of service. If this answers your question, then you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow on the left, and mark it as solved by clicking the tick.

Comment: I just did it. Thanks.